# Mapbox-gl typing won't allow accessToken assignment

Tags: typescript, mapbox

I'm using the mapbox-gl library with TypeScript, and I've installed its community sourced type definitions with `@types/mapbox-gl`. When I try to import and set an accessToken to use the library, my TypeScript compiler throws this error: 
`TS2540: Cannot assign to 'accessToken' because it is a constant or a read-only property.`

So I pulled up the .d.ts file and the variable in question looks extremely assignable (seen here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mapbox-gl/index.d.ts):

```
declare namespace mapboxgl {
   let accessToken: string;
   ...
```

This is my code:

```
import * as mapbox from 'mapbox-gl';
mapbox.accessToken = 'token';
```

Versions!

```
"@types/mapbox-gl": "^0.35.0",
"typescript": "^2.3.4",
"mapbox-gl": "^0.37.0",
```

TypeScript hackery says that I can cast mapbox to any and it will work, but I'm very curious what about the typing is going wrong here.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here's a temporary workaround I've been using:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(mapboxgl, "accessToken").set('YOUR_TOKEN');
```

#### Explanation

Since the object was redefined to use a custom setter which places the token inside an internal closure - we can call the setter function directly as shown in the example.

Diving a little deeper, we can see that es6 modules are constants by definition: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6751#issuecomment-177114001

we can then do something like: `(mapboxgl as any).accessToken = ..`. which will work.

Comment: (mapboxgl as any).accessToken = ... <---doesn't work either, 
                                                                   
 Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(mapboxgl, "accessToken").set('YOUR_TOKEN'); <-- works fine.

Answer (score 25):

For those finding this now ... You don't even need to set the Mapbox `accessToken` this way, it can be passed in as an option (since v1.2)

```js
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  accessToken: '...',
  container: '...',
  style: '...',
});
```

Pity it's not the method used in any of the examples (yet).

Docs: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map

1.2 release notes: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/releases/tag/v1.2.0

PR that adds it: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/8364

Comment: I'm using a helper function based on this to inject a default token: `import { Map as MapboxMap, MapboxOptions } from 'mapbox-gl'; export const createMap = (config: MapboxOptions): MapboxMap => new MapboxMap({ accessToken: MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN, ...config })`

Answer (score 4):

You can also use this format:

```
(mapboxgl as typeof mapboxgl).accessToken = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid both kind of errors.

1. **Imports are Immutable error** during the compilation phase when directly setting this as

   `mapboxgl.accessToken = 'YOUR_TOKEN';`
2. **set is not a function error** on the browser when you have hosted your compiled artifact with the static method

   `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(mapboxgl, "accessToken"). set(YOUR_TOKEN');`

You nee to directly set this on the `ACCESS_TOKEN` property present on `mapboxgl.config`

```
import * as mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

mapboxgl.config.ACCESS_TOKEN = 'YOUR_TOKEN';
```